# iOS - SMS Security Code Autofill Localisation Support

Tags: ios, hebrew

Following WWDC2017 session - [Introducing Password AutoFill for Apps[1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206) -I've successfully implemented parsing an SMS security code and presenting it on the system keyboard's `QuickType Bar`:

[image: https://docs-assets.developer.apple.com/published/02567a70eb/11b8e670-8e62-47e1-9f35-67189085e80c.png]

The only problem is, it seems that the SMS message must be in English for the `API` to work.
An SMS message in a non-Latin language, like Hebrew in my case, didn't trigger the `API`.

I thought Apple had local support for this,
am I missing something or is this `API` currently not supported for languages other than English?

Comment: Hi! Had you find something regarding this? I am looking for the same thing!

Comment: Afraid not , and I still can’t seem to use This API in non-English Syntax

Comment: Ok, So I am able to send localised massage in Hebrew. It seems the format is: #Number# Rest Of Your Massage.
Meaning the One Time Code Number must be at the start of the massage.
Rough translation from Hebrew, the SMS massage reads: “12345 is your One Time Code”